# Mac + Wine, running .bat with Drag/Drop for Spyro World Viewer

Tags: macos, batch-file, wine

I am trying to get [Spyro World Viewer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THkI6FJ2jDc) (Video here) to work on Mac, and the .exe itself runs great. To include the worlds however, shown in the video I am trying to execute a [.bat file](http://pastebin.com/tRxkQijy) (Pasted here) with Wine and it uses some sort of Drag/Drop method, where I drop a .WAD file onto the .bat. I'm no Windows user, but I'm guessing this is something like a .sh file. I've attempted opening Wine's DOS Prompt, to execute `cmd < Full_Spyro2_norm.bat "..\..\Spyro2.WAD"` but that doesn't seem to help. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Type `cmd /?` see `/c` and `/k` switches.

Comment: What are you trying to pull from the .wad file?